# Receiving an answer which is not clear and has ambiguities

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers, specific-answer

I asked a question, and I received an answer (see here: [Non-isomorphicity of certain fields.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3878563/non-isomorphicity-of-certain-fields)). But the answer is not clear to me, and it has too many ambiguities for me. I've tried too much and thought a lot about it, but I cannot understand it. I think this phenomenon has happened before to me. What suggestions do you recommend me to do?

---

Edited: I'm embarrassed to say this, I do not think that is a mathematical proof, and I think it has a fundamental bug that cannot be fixed. Of course, I can not tell if it is wrong or not. (I do not want to discuss more on this question, I just add more details about my opinion on that question, to be more precise.)

Comment: At this point in normal human interaction, it is natural to *talk with the author*.  If eventually you’re still not satisfied, it would be natural to *wait*. Or if you’ve waited a week or two and ent to stir the pot, offer a bounty.

Comment: What's wrong with the obvious?  Post comments asking for clarification.  It's better, of course, if you can ask clear questions.  Just repeating "I don't understand." doesn't give anyone much to work with.  Is there a technical point you don't understand?  Does the solution cite an unfamiliar result or concept?  That sort of thing.

Comment: @rschwieb I talked with the author, but I didn't convince. The problem is that: my experience says that after two weeks, new questions will come to mind, and unfortunately old questions will be forgotten.

Comment: Leave a comment below the answer to ask for further clarification of the ambiguities. If the answerer does not respond or does not explain them in a way you can understand, you can start a bounty on your question with a note that it will be awarded to any answer that is able to fully resolve such ambiguities. In some cases it may also be appropriate to ask a new question focusing entirely on parts of the answer you are unsure about.

Comment: @lulu I had too many ambiguities with the answer, and I asked 4 clear questions, about some of my ambiguities. But yet I did not receive an answer for at least 3 of them. The solution does not cite an unfamiliar result. But I am stuck in some points, and I don't have any idea about the following parts.

Comment: I see..  Well, if the ambiguities are big enough, they could be phrased as new questions. Or offer a bonus, as others have suggested.  You will have noticed, however, that the site is not conducive to in depth discussions of complex, ambiguous points.  Rather, it centers around short answers to short, self-contained questions.  That's not to say that in depth analysis is not a good thing of course!  Just that nothing can replace one on one discussions or a full classroom experience.

Comment: It is difficult for us to assess your situation, because you failed to identify or link your question.  Answers are sometimes ambiguous due to ambiguous questions.  Since you fail to provide more context in this meta.math.se post, anyone's answer or comment is nothing more than a stab in the dark.

Comment: @amWhy I was not sure whether it was ethical to link to the question. But now I added the link to that question. Thank you so much for pointing out this problem.

Comment: Neo  Your options are as follows: any or all of the following actions (1) downvote the answer, (2) do not accept an answer you do not find helpful, (3) patiently await someone else's answer.  You post has not even been alive for a full day yet.

Comment: Also please realize this is a Q&A site, and it's not terribly fond of long discussions in comments.  That is, this site is not a discussion forum.  Perhaps you need to improve your question, but please realize there is a close reason "needs more focus" for questions that  include too many questions.  So don't be surprised if, after asking four questions in comments, that some may find doing so unwelcome.

Comment: Dear @amWhy I think the main question is asking clearly one question. Also, I think the answer to that question is very hard to follow, and I can give some reasons that that answer is hard to follow for almost every starting student in algebraic number theory.

Comment: I've added the specific-question tag, although I was conflicted about whether the less-used specific-answer tag might be better suited.  Feel free to change (or use both) as you wish.  I'll post an answer to  this meta Question if you are interested, along the lines of what you (as the asker on main) might profitably do in this or similar cases.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you so much, your answer is welcome.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I asked a new question, and I point out that the third part of the answer is not clear to me (Being honest, I think maybe the answer is wrong!). But until now, I received 5 down-votes (with just 13 views!). So I think asking a new question to focus on some parts of the answer is not going to work.